# Finding the Path of a shared folder with Python

Tags: python

I am working on a shared server where there is no specific folder structure I can work with on an intranet. I have the folder path where my .py file is placed on the following path:

```
 \\SERVERNAME\FOLDER1$\FOLDER2\
```

My goal is to find such folder1 because I need to access some other files on a different subfoler3 of folder1$. I am using the os.abspath to find this:

```
 ServerPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

My issue is that when I run this from a pyinstaller .exe generated file from a task scheduler on the server, it does not find the expected path and fails.

How can I get the proper file path?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Do you get a traceback?

Comment: It stated it can't find the path on the server. It identifies the path properly, but it can't reach the folder

Comment: please, copy-paste the actual error message?